# How do you change rpc password?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I'm trying to run bitcoind with a changed conf file, but for some reason the password it thinks is incorrect. Is there a way I can change the rpc username and password?

Comment: Can you include in your question the exact content of the file (with password masked out if needed), the command you run, the output you expect, the output you see, entries in debug.log that may be relevant? It's very hard to help based on vague observations.

Answer (score 2):

1. `bitcoin-cli stop`
2. Then edit your bitcoin.conf with `nano bitcoin.conf`
3. Then edit or add the entry `rpcpassword=yourpassword` and `rpcusername=yourusername`
4. Save it
5. Restart bitcoind

Answer (score 0):

If you try to stop the bitcoind using bitcoin-cli then try edit the bitcoin.conf file to change the login and if that do not work then reboot then change the login (not sure if bitcoind can stop the server)

Comment: I already tried changing the rpcuser and rpcpassword in bitcoin.conf and restarting the server with the new config file

Comment: Ok then try to stop the daemon and simplely change the password and username to what you want and start the daemon again

Comment: No the problem is when trying to restart daemon with new config, it says invalid credentials

Comment: Ik but you have to stop the daemon with the same credentials then change it or else it won't work